# Mathematics with and without continuum hypothesis

Tags: cardinals

This is a follow-up to [a recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215123/decidability-of-the-cardinality-of-a-set-given-that-the-continuum-hypothesis-is]).

Are there "interesting" differences between CH-mathematics and (non-CH)-mathematics? Has anybody developed mathematics with c = $\aleph_2$? $\aleph_3$? ... $\aleph_{\omega}$?